# Why can't I access the files on my SD card?

Tags: external-sd, file-system, encryption

I have a Motorola Droid Bionic which I recently updated to Android 4.1.2. Since the update, I can no longer access any of the files on the 32GB micro SD card I installed in the phone. I can *view all the filenames and directories*, but when I try to open any of the files, I am unable to.

Settings -> Storage tells me that the SD card is mounted at `/storage/sdcard1`

I had previously enabled "Memory card encryption" under Settings -> Security & Screen Lock -> Data encryption, and I believe this is likely the issue. I must have enabled this over a year ago, likely shortly around when I first got the phone.

I just noticed this issue a few days ago. I did the update last week. I am not sure if the update caused the issue, but it seems the likely cause because it's the only thing I have changed recently.

Trying to play music from the SD card (in three different players) displays the error "Could not play this track" for every song. Trying to view images on the card displays the message "Could not read file".

The phone is not rooted. I have a pin enabled which I need to enter when the phone boots and on the lock screen.

Why can't I access the files on my SD card, and what can I do to recover these files?

Comment: Are you still using password unlock with the same password you used before the update? Have you reenabled SD card encryption?

Comment: I am not using a password unlock. I don't believe I ever was. I might have enabled that when I first got my phone, but I am using a pin unlock now and have been for as long as I can remember. I was using a pin unlock last time I was able to access the SD card files.

Comment: I disabled and re-enabled SD card encryption with no effect.