# Why can't I access my files on my SD card after marshmallow update?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, external-sd, data-recovery

I have a AT&T galaxy note 4 which recently updated to 6.0.1 Marshmallow.

My phone reads that the SD card is in there, and all the file directories are there but when I try to open or view them it'll tell me I can't open/view the file. My music player still reads all the music just can't play them, ("could not play this track") or my gallery still has all the photos but can't display them

All photos show as:

[image]

The phone is not rooted but is encrypted along with the SD card. I tried decrypting it but it didn't do anything, along with taking out the SD card, cleaning it, ect.

It seems though I can add data to the card and it will save new data to the card.

What can I do to fix or recover my data? thanks.

Also, my problem is very similar to the one below, except under different circumstances.

[Why can't I access the files on my SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44734/why-cant-i-access-the-files-on-my-sd-card)

Answer (score -2):

You have to provide run time permission for that.